# sql how to get where="all"

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

hi i want to create a search box in my website i have done all thing but i want to know that i have 3 search boxes and 1st one is of city second is of location and 3rd is type. it works when user selects something in all 3 boxes but i want to know that what SQL query to use when user selects ALL in any one or more then one boxes.
example - this is what i am doing

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM employe WHERE date=$date AND reason='$reason' AND    month='$month' ";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

this is what i want

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM employe WHERE date='ALL' AND reason='ALL' AND month='$month' ";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

it should be $date there but just to explain i have written all so you guys can understand what i want

Comment: If you want to give the user the ability to search for **all** records, it's the same as no filtering at all, so you just need remove the `reason = '$reason'` from your query (if `$reason == 'ALL'`).

Comment: yes so will it work if i   <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
    <option value="*">ALL</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>

Comment: then i have to run multiple queries if i use $reason=='ALL' because there is a probabilty that user select all in first box or second box or 3rd box or any two box or no box or all box

Comment: You don't need to have multiple queries, but your code should have several `if` sections, and the final query depends on them.

Comment: but query will change according to if statement , yes or no

Comment: I think I know what you'rea asking here. If the goal here is to show all the rows found in the user's search, then you need loop over the entire results, something you left out in your question as to "how" you are showing those results to the user, am I getting warm here?

Comment: @AnayPareek, yes, you are correct. The query *should* change according to the `if` statements.

Comment: if($_SESSION["s1"]!=="ALL" &&  $_SESSION["s2"]=="ALL" && $_SESSION["s3"]=="ALL")
{
 
 $query_pag_data = "SELECT * from seller WHERE locality='$location' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$query_pag_data);

Comment: i want to know fred that is there any way that i can run a single qyery and execute search result using if else or something else

Comment: Why the usage of `$_SESSION` there?

Comment: dekel if i have 3 search boxes then i have to run 9 queries thats why i wanted to know an alternate way

Comment: nothing i have used same 3 boxes somewhere else and did it same way u are saying but creating different queries so i used session to get value there

Comment: but i dont want it hard this time so i want to know about a real way how it is done if we have 3 search boxes and select ALL in any of the box

Comment: No, you always need to run **1** query.

Comment: Too basic question, just don't put any condition in that case...

Comment: yeah right what if he selects some city in list then what... if i will not add any condition

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to build condition string and use it for sql statement. like this

```
if($date=='ALL' or $date==''){
     $datecond='';
}
else{
$datecond = " and date='$date' ";
}
if($reason=='ALL' or $reason==''){
$reasoncond='';
}
else{
$reasoncond=" and reason='$reason'";
}
if($month=='ALL' or $month==''){
$monthcond = '';
}
else{
$monthcond = " and month='$month'";
}
$sql = "select * from employee where 1 $datecond $reasoncond $monthcond";
```